# How to resolve "Access is denied" error when calling spyder in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

Good day,

We recently adopted environments in anaconda after having some dependency issues. Spyder is our preferred IDE and gets installed for each environment. Only the user who created the environment can open spyder, any other user gets an error "access is denied" when they try to run spyder. We would like to ask some help to give multiple users access to spyder.

The following approach was used to create the enviroments:

- Installed Miniconda on a Windows machine and specified that installation is for all users
- Created a folder on the C: drive called "MinicondaEnvironments"
- Created an environment for each project using Anaconda Prompt by running the following command:
  "conda create --prefix C:\MinicondaEnvironments\project_name"
- Installed spyder for each environment by running the following commands: "conda activate C:\MinicondaEnvironments\project_name" followed by "conda install spyder"

The error can be reproduced with the following steps:

- Shift + Right Click on Anaconda Prompt and select "Run as other user"
- Activate environment "conda activate C:\MinicondaEnvironments\project_name"
- Call spyder in Anaconda Prompt by running "spyder"
- "Access is denied" is returned in Anaconda Prompt

Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the folder `C:\MinicondaEnvironments\project_name`? Is it read/write access for all users?

Comment: Yes I have, thank you for the suggestion. I followed the instructions on the conda docs to create a user group and gave them read/write access to the directory. See link for further info - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was due to a strange file permission issue for the spyder/app/start.py file. The following fixed it:

1. right click the environment folder and click “properties”
2. Go to “Security”
3. Click “advanced”
4. Click “Add”
5. Beside “Principal” click “select a principal”
6. Type “computerName\Users”
7. Click Ok
8. Under “Basic Permissions” tick “Full Control”
9. Click ok
10. At the bottom of the window tick the box beside “Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object”
11. Click OK